# Android crop image just after taking from camera and display by picking from gallery

Tags: android, image, android-intent, crop, onactivityresult

In my app there is an activity taking a picture from camera, saving it and displaying on ImageView followingby. I use **FilePath** class to point where to store it on a path and **CameraUtils** class to get *file:URI* and convert the image to *BitMap*. Now my task is to add a crop functionality to get rid of areas that are out of our interests. The crop function should activate on the screen just after a picture taken and then cropped photo need to be saved to display. Before that please see the working codes before crop added:

I have this method to capture an image:

```js
    /*  Capture Image Method  */
        private void captureImage() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);//Start intent with Action_Image_Capture
            fileUri = CameraUtils.getOutputMediaFileUri(this);//get fileUri from CameraUtils
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);//Send fileUri with intent
            //intent.putExtra("return-data",true); // Should be for crop
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);//start activity for result with CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE
        }
```

This method to show captured image

```js
    /*  Show Captured over ImageView  */
        private void showCapturedImage() {
            if (!getImageUrl.equals("") && getImageUrl != null)
                imageView.setImageBitmap(CameraUtils.convertImagePathToBitmap(getImageUrl, false));
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.capture_image_failed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

The method to crop image:

```js
private void CropImage() {

        try {
            Intent CropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            CropIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");

            CropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            CropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 180);
            CropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 180);
            CropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 3);
            CropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 4);
            CropIntent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);
            CropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

            startActivityForResult(CropIntent, 1003);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            //
        }
    }
```

onActivityResult() method:

```js
/**
 * public static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1001;//request code for Camera and External Storage permission
 * private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 1002;//request code for capture image
 * private static final int CROP_REQUEST_CODE = 1003;//request code for crop
 */

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {

            case CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE:
                try {
                    //When image is captured successfully
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        //Check if device SDK is greater than 22 then we get the actual image path via below method
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22)
                            getImageUrl = FilePath.getPath(MainActivity.this, fileUri);
                        else
                            //else we will get path directly
                            getImageUrl = fileUri.getPath();

                        //After image capture show captured image over image view
                        showCapturedImage();

                    } else
                        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.cancel_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Till this point everthing works very well but when it comes to inserting the  crop function, I'm struggling with adding if else/statements with required requestCodes into switch/case statements as it throws an unknown errors. Can you help me with the creating the proper logic with multiple requstCodes and make it work, please?

Comment: Please post the exact error you get (logcat)

Comment: Hello. I meant it sends a toast msg on the screen stating "unknown error". the app doesnt crash. I'm assuming it's bcs of unhandled empty exception statement

Answer (score 1):

After making the following changes I could make it working.

First of all CropIntent was passing value through key-pair values which was supposed to pass through MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT and the uri was not defined with correct name.

```js
private void CropImage() {

        try {
            Intent CropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            CropIntent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "image/*");
            fileUri = CameraUtils.getOutputMediaFileUri(this);

            CropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            CropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 180);
            CropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 180);
            CropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 3);
            CropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 4);
            CropIntent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);
            CropIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

            startActivityForResult(CropIntent, CROP_REQUEST_CODE);

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            //
        }
    }
```

Second, I replaced switch/case statement with if/else in onActivityResult()

```js
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                CropImage();

        } else if (requestCode == CROP_REQUEST_CODE) {
                //Check if device SDK is greater than 22 then we get the actual image path via below method
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22)
                    getImageUrl = FilePath.getPath(MainActivity.this, fileUri);
                else
                    //else we will get path directly
                    getImageUrl = fileUri.getPath();
                //After image capture show captured image over image view
                showCapturedImage();
            }
        }
```